# Conditional formatting pivot bar chart based on criteria in another table

Tags: excel, conditional-formatting, pivot-chart

I am creating Bar PivotCharts in Excel and am trying to colour the bars by a condition in another table i.e for each "Round" value in the Pivot chart the values would be green In games where the result was W and red in games where the result was L.

I have attempted overlaying another data source but as one is a numerical value and one is a text value this isnt working.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.